# error while saving a dictionary into mysql table from python code

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to save a dict into mysql table, whose keys are columns and values are rows. This dict has keys which is a subset of all the columns of a table. I am using below code in python

```
sql_dict = {'deviceID': 'fd00::212:4b00:1957:d1b1', 'date': '2020-02-22', 'timestamp': '18:39:29.620329', 'counter': 72, 'rssi': 59, 'CH_1_Leavinng_Chiller_Liq_Temp': 7.7, 'CH_1_Motor_Current_limit_SP': 7.8, 'CH_1_Leaving_Condensor_liq_temp': 36.1, 'CH_1_Motor_Current_Percentage': 9.9, 'CH_1_Discharge_temp': 45.1, 'CH_1_Oil_Sump_temp': 45.6, 'CH_1_Remote_start_stop': 0.0, 'CH_1_Variable_speed_type': 0.0, 'Bypass line temp sensor ': -1274.8}
```

```
sql_insert_query = """ INSERT INTO Data {} VALUES {}""".format(tuple(sql_dict.keys()), tuple(sql_dict.values()))
```

I get an error when i run my code

```
Failed inserting record into python_users table 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''deviceID', 'date', 'timestamp', 'counter', 'rssi', 'CH_1_Leavinng_Chiller_Liq_T'
```

I don't understand where am I going wrong. Can someone help me with this ?

My table desc for reference

[image]

Comment: Print out `sql_dict.keys()` and `tuple(sql_dict.values())`. It looks like there is a special character causing this.

Comment: There is a problem because of missing quotes around the varchar values, because the resulting string would look like `INSERT INTO Data (abcd:casd, )` however follow @Tin Nguyen's answer

Comment: my sql_dict varies constantly, thats the reason I am try to do that way I am doing, filling those columns which are part of dict, rest as null.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following syntax to insert values into your database

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", (var1, var2, var3))
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table VALUES (?, ?, ?)", (var1, var2, var3))
```

Else you are opening yourself to SQL injection attacks. https://xkcd.com/327/

Another problem is the keys in your dictionary don't match the table columns in your screenshot. `deviceID` until `rssi` matches but `CH_1_Leavinng_Chiller_Liq_Temp` doesn't match. So the error likely comes from here.

**edit**:
From your example this would be the SQL query:

```
INSERT INTO Data (
  'deviceID', 'date', 'timestamp', 
  'counter', 'rssi', 'CH_1_Leavinng_Chiller_Liq_Temp', 
  'CH_1_Motor_Current_limit_SP', 'CH_1_Leaving_Condensor_liq_temp', 'CH_1_Motor_Current_Percentage', 
  'CH_1_Discharge_temp', 'CH_1_Oil_Sump_temp', 'CH_1_Remote_start_stop', 
  'CH_1_Variable_speed_type', 'Bypass line temp sensor '
) VALUES (
  'fd00::212:4b00:1957:d1b1', '2020-02-22', '18:39:29.620329', 
  72, 59, 7.7, 
  7.8, 36.1, 9.9, 
  45.1, 45.6, 0.0, 
  0.0, -1274.8
)"
```

The datatype for `counter` and `rssi` is `varchar`. Here you are however providing a number, not string.

Comment: I haven't shown the complete columns of my table. `CH_1_Leavinng_Chiller_Liq_Temp ` is also a column

Comment: Edited my answer with another problem I noticed. If that doesn't resolve it please include the `CREATE ...` sql query in your question. You can deduce from them valid `INSERT ...` sql queries.

Comment: I dont want to hard code. How to use something like `sql_insert_query = """ INSERT INTO chillerData keys_tuple VALUES values_tuple"""`

Comment: Did my edit resolve your original problem? You can build the string `INSERT INTO Data (?, ?, ?) VALUES (?, ?, ?)` dynamically depending on how many items your dictionary has. Run this in your python console `",".join(["?"]*5)` the 5 you can make variable depending on your amount of dictionary items.
I also edited the `INSERT INTO ...` syntax since I do not know which syntax you are using. It depends on your libraries. You have to try it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `tuple` to format SQL strings as you are doing, for a couple of reasons:

- It doesn't work for table column names, because they should not be surrounded with single quotes.  Surround them with backticks instead, so your `INSERT` statement looks like

```sql
    INSERT INTO Data (`deviceId`, `date`, `timestamp`, ...
```

- If a string value contains a `'` character, this will cause Python to output the string using double-quote rather than single-quote characters.  Whether MySQL accepts double-quoted string literals or not I don't know, but other databases definitely don't.  There is also, as pointed out by @TinNguyen, the risk of SQL injection, so you should be using parameterised SQL for your string values.

Instead, try something like the following:

```
column_names = ", ".join("`{0}`".format(key) for key in sql_dict)
placeholders = ", ".join(["%s"] * len(sql_dict))
sql_insert_query = """ INSERT INTO Data ({}) VALUES ({})""".format(column_names, placeholders)
# execute the insert using cursor.execute(sql_insert_query, tuple(sql_dict.values()))
```

Here, we build up the parts of the `INSERT` statement using the `.join()` method on strings: it looks a bit odd because it's a method on the joining string, `", "`.  Note that neither of `column_names` nor `placeholders` begin nor end with parentheses `(` and `)` so these must be added to the SQL string we call `.format()` on: I've replaced both occurrences of `{}` with `({})`.